# Understanding syntax of Storage filesystem in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, local-storage, laravel-5.6, laravel-filesystem

[image]

I'm searching for this syntax but I cannot find any explanation... I found some examples but everyone is using the method storeAs(), store() or move() straight away.

I can't understand what $file_contents is. What is this for? What shall it contain?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just uploading the file

Comment: OK.  Did you read the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: No, I`m not reading anyone, just uploading them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put is used to store contents in a file.  So `$file_content` being the data you want to store in `'filename'`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#storing-files

This would be similar to file_put_contents.

Comment: It will create the file if it doesn't exist.  This works the same as file_put_contents.

Comment: Now I understand, is not the proper syntax to upload files.